# 500 server error while using 301 redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

I tried the following lines in .htaccess file and put it in includes folder:

```
//301 Redirect Old File
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 includes/config.php includes/index.php
```

I want when any user opens this file using url that he/she must be redirect to includes/index.php file.
But I got the 500 server error.

Comment: show us your ``.htaccess`` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason of your 500 error is: **`Redirect to non-URL`**

As you're missing leading slash in your matching pattern and target URL.

Use this rule to fix it:

```
Redirect 301 /includes/config.php /includes/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Redirect 301 /includes/config.php http://yoursite.com/includes/index.php
```

Although, if the htaccess is in the includes dir then you don't need /includes at all. 
The second url must also be full - as above.